# Concatenation syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Cannot get this statement to update the table and am almost certain my problem is in concatenation syntax.

Please take a look and tell me if you see what I am going wrong here..

Thank you !!

```
UPDATE TAB1 s  
        SET s.user_NUM =   
             (select e.USER# 
                  from TAB2 e   
                  where ('e.LAST_NAME'||','||' E.FIRST_NAME')= s.DEALER);
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors while executing this SQL statement?

Comment: Why were you quoted `'e.LAST_NAME'` and `'E.FIRST_NAME'`. They appear to be column names in your *database table* and `E.FIRST_NAME` should not be there rather it should be `e.FIRST_NAME`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think those are supposed to be columns in TAB2?  If so, you need to drop the quote marks:

```
UPDATE TAB1 s
        SET s.user_NUM =   
             (select e.USER# 
                  from TAB2 e   
                  where (e.LAST_NAME||', '||E.FIRST_NAME)= s.DEALER);
```

Otherwise you're looking to match records in TAB1 `where DEALER = 'e.LAST_NAME, E.FIRST_NAME'` (i.e. a literal), which I don't think is what you meant at all.

---

> "When I put a space behind the comma, I got an error that a single row
>   query returns more than one row."

So, more than one row in TAB2 matches a row in TAB1.  This now becomes an investigation into your data.

If there is only one occurrence of `e.USER#` for `e.LAST_NAME||', '||E.FIRST_NAME` you're fine: you can just add DISTINCT into the sub-query.  Check that with:

```
select e.LAST_NAME||', '||E.FIRST_NAME
       , count(distinct e.USER#) 
from TAB2 e   
group by e.LAST_NAME||', '||E.FIRST_NAME
      having count(distinct e.USER#) > 1
```

If that query returns any rows you're going to need to decide how to handle multiple hits.

Likewise, you need to decide what action to take if there is no row in TAB2 which matches a row in TAB1.  At the moment that's going to set `s.user_NUM` to NULL.  Maybe that's what you want.

These are decisions about business rules: only you know what you want to do.

Comment: There are multiple listings! Is that keeping the original statement from working?  I would be happy to select any one of the multiples, since the user# will be the same in each.  Thank you!!!!

Comment: I GOT IT!!! By adding and rownum =1, the original statemnt populated the rows!!!!!   Thank you one and all...............

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be with `E.FIRST_NAME` which should be replaced by `e.FIRST_NAME`

```
UPDATE TAB1 s
    SET s.user_NUM =   
         (select e.USER# 
              from TAB2 e   
              where (e.LAST_NAME||','||e.FIRST_NAME)= s.DEALER);
```

Comment: dropping the quotes and lower casing e, get no errors, just get no population, even though it says the rows are updated.

Comment: The table alias `e` will be case insensitive in Oracle. (And other RDBMs that I am familiar with)

Comment: What are the types of the columns?  Do you need to worry about trailing blanks (stripping them?), or do you need a space after the comma?  Whatever you do, be very wary of a sub-query in the SET clause where there is no matching WHERE clause in the main UPDATE; it will set the `user_NUM` to null in any rows in TAB1 (in this example) where there isn't a matching row in TAB2.

Comment: I think you may be on to something.  When I put a space behind the comma, I got an error that a single row query returns more than one row... How would yoou rewrite it with a where in both parts?  Thank you for your help, by the way, i do appreciate it.